# Calendar for iOS with week, day and month view

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar, mbcalendarkit

Can anyone suggest me a good calendar for iOS that has a day view, week view and a month view. Something similar to `MBCalendarKit` which I downloaded from

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=&q=calendar

When I integrate this calendar in my application using `storyboard`, I am not able to see the bottom buttons as seen in the image below.

Can anyone suggest me how to remove this bug or can you guys suggest me a good alternative for this? I tried almost all the calendars available like tapku, Kal etc.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated MBCalendarKit with my App using storyboard. I just had to make the view controller in the storyboard to which I am connecting the MBCalendarKit as a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout i created day view using Tapku library [DayView](https://github.com/safecase123/Calender)

For `WeekView` and `MonthView` use [Tapku library](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)

I have customized to some extent just like `iCalender`

Comment: Week view? I don't see one in Tapku library.